# Running a continuous Python process and memory management

Tags: python

My current assignment is to run a Python program continuously, it is going to be a cron job kind of thing, internally it will have objects which is going to be updated every 24hrs and then basically write the details in a file.

Some advice required about the memory management

1. Should I use single process or multi threaded. As there is a scope in the program which can be done parallel. As it is going to run continuously some clarification would be required about the memory consumption of these threads also do I need to cleanup the resources of the threads after each execution. Is there any clean up method available for threads in python.
2. When I do a object allocation in Python, do I need to think about the destructor as well or Python will do the gc.

Please share your thoughts on this as well as what would be the best approach.

Comment: Python has automatic memory management. Whether you should use a single process, multiple processes, or multiple threads (which are different) depends on much more than memory considerations.

Comment: I agree with you.I just wanted to get clarified that for memory I don't have to worry in Python.

Comment: Now When I am running this process infinitely,I do see a increase in memory every hour.Is there a memory leak happening ?

Comment: That depends on your definition of a memory leak. If you expect it to run in constant memory then yes, there is a leak. If you are building a larger and larger data structure in memory then no leak.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a misunderstanding in your question.

A cron job is a scheduled task that runs at a given interval of time. A program running continuously doesn't need to be scheduled, aside from being launched at boot.

First, multi-threading in Python suffers the [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), so unless you are calling multi-threading aware library functions or your computations are I/O bound (often blocked by input/output such as disk access, network access and such) that releases the GIL, you will only have an insubstantial gain by using threading. You should though consider using the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) package for parallel computing. Other options are NumPy-based calculations when the library is compiled with OpenMP or using a task-based parallel framework such as [SCOOP](https://code.google.com/p/scoop/) or [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/).

As stated in the comments, memory management is built in in Python and you won't have to worry about it apart from deleting unused instances or elements. Python will garbage collect your program automatically for every element that doesn't have any variable bound to it, so be sure to delete them or let them fall off-scope accordingly.

On a side-note, be careful with objects destructors in Python, they tend to exhibit a different behavior than other Object Oriented languages. I recommend you reading of this matter before using them.

Comment: There are also a handful of great persistent process frameworks for writing daemons of all sorts.  Off the top of my head: Twisted, Eventlet, Gevent.